# Magento2 to Magento2 data migration

Tags: magento2, data-migration

What is the best way to migrate sales and customer data from a magento2 site, to another Magento2 site?

A site has been in development for a few months, the changes made are so extensive, that it seems easier to update the development site DB, with fresh live customer/sales/product data.

Customer and address import hopefully is as easy as using the export/import admin tool (Hopefuly when sales data is migrated, the imported customers will tally up with the associated orders - if associations are made using the email addresses....as I am unsure at the moment if the customer IDs imported will be the same)

I am going to try migrate sales data by exporting all the sales related tables, and import into the dev DB copy.

See how I get on, but if anyone has any tips for a M2 to M2 migration?

Comment: Did the same some months ago, you will have to prepare some mysql queries to pump over the data. 

1) both sites in maintenance.
2) take db backup from both instances.
3) import db on new server.
4) run your sql scripts.

Some handy tips:

- make sure customer attributes are correctly mapped
- make sure product sku's are correctly mapped for the sales data
- make sure encryption key is the same

Answer (score 0):

Will you be interested in using an extension on Magento marketplace? If yes, please check this one out.

https://marketplace.magento.com/litextension-magento2-upgrade.html